# TNS-01153 Failed to process String

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I am trying to restart the listener in my Oracle 11g installation and I get the error:

```
TNS-01153 Failed to process String: -
```

and this is my listener.ora. I can't figure out where the error is:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = name.comp.com)(PORT = 1521))
)
)

LISTENER_MSORA =
 (ADDRESS_LIST=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522))
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))

SID_LIST_LISTENER_MSORA=
 (SID_LIST=
  (SID_DESC=
     (SID_NAME=MSORA)
     (ORACLE_HOME = d:\oracle\product\10.1.0\db_1)
     (PROGRAM=hsodbc)
   )
  )  
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\oracle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a windows server so, I stopped TNSlistner service, opened up Oracle net manager and deleted the old listener and created a new one, restarted TNSlistner service. This resolved the issue.